# Reading in a text file from a command line and storing the content of the file into a c-string

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, ifstream, c-strings

I am learning C++ in one of my classes and I am having difficulties storing the content of a .txt file into a c string.

I have figured out how to validate that the .txt file exists but when I try storing the characters into a c-string it crashes.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
char * fileContent[MAX_SIZE];
ifstream ifile(argv[1]);
while (int i = 0 < MAX_SIZE)
{
    ifile >> fileContent[i];
    cout << fileContent[i];
    if (ifile.eof())
        break;
    i++;
}
ifile.close();
```

Every-time the console gets to the loop it crashes. Are there any suggestions to help make this work?

I need it to be a c-string so that I can run the c-string through other functions. I am still pretty new to C++.

The assignment states: "Reads a text file into memory, one byte at a time"
I hope what I am trying to do is this.
Thank you

Comment: Change "char * fileContent[MAX_SIZE]" to  "string fileContent[MAX_SIZE]" and try.

Comment: Take another look at your condition in the while loop.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar That won't read one byte at a time.

Comment: `char c; while (ifile >> c) { /* whatevs */ }`

Comment: @NeilKirk Or he may change  "char * fileContent[MAX_SIZE]"  to  "char  fileContent[MAX_SIZE]"

Comment: Furthermore don't hardcode max sizes when reading files. Either it wastes memory or will break with a large file.

Comment: @NeilKirk - that worked except it took out the spaces from the input file. Also, I thought you had to set a size for an array in C++. I don't know any other way. I have some experience in javascript but I know in that language you don't have to set anysize.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar I am required to use c-strings and pointers.

Comment: `ifile >> noskipws` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/

Comment: Use vector and it has resize function and push_back function. `ifile >> noskipws; vector<char> text; char c; while (ifile >> c) { text.push_back(c); }`

Comment: @NeilKirk After changing char * fileContent to char fileContent [] I used "char c; while (ifile >> noskipws>> c) { fileContent[i] = c; }" It worked but it is showing the 0 at the end. Im assuming that is the null character is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

There were few bugs in your code, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int MAX_SIZE = 128; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char fileContent[MAX_SIZE]; //bad idea never do that!
                                // use an std::vector<char> instead!
                                // and reverse a minimum amount of chars 
                                // using `reserve` if you are after performance
    ifstream ifile(argv[1]);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < MAX_SIZE)
    {
        ifile >> fileContent[i];
        cout << fileContent[i];
        if (ifile.eof())
            break;
        i++;
    }
    ifile.close();
}
```

Comment: I did this but it says that it is expecting a '{' after the [i];

Comment: Try now, you had an array of pointers to char. you need an array of char

Comment: I did this and added the noskipws but it gives a weird character and a number at the end.

Comment: Use a debugger, the above code is tested and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to read from a text file and save the string as a C-string. The output file (output.txt) contains the c-string output.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main()
{

    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);

    char *out_c_string;
    char ch;
    int index=0;

    while(cin >> ch)
        out_c_string[index++] = ch;


    for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
        cout << out_c_string[i]; // the c string of the file :)


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining everyones answers, I got this as my function:

```
void get_file_info(char * argv, char (&fileContent) [MAX_SIZE], int & filesize ){
    freopen(argv, "r", stdin);
    char ch;
    int index = 0;

    while (cin >> noskipws >> ch)
        fileContent[index++] = ch;
    cout << endl << index << endl;

#if SHOW_DEBUG_CODE
    for (int count = 0; count < index; count++)
        cout << fileContent[count];
#endif

    fclose(stdin);
}
```

It seems to work just fine. I will look into vectors my next free time but for right now, I am going to continue with char array.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this. It's more general to cope with any size file.

```
void ReadFile(char*file,char**buff,int*size){

    // Open file as binary putting file position at the end
    ifstream is(file,ios::binary|ios::ate);

    // Get the current file position, which is the file end
    *size=is.tellg();

    // Put file pointer back at the start
    is.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    // errors
    if (!*size){
        cout<<"Unable to open input file or file empty\n";
        exit(9);
    }

    // allocate a buffer one bigger to allow for zero terminator
    *buff=new char[*size+1];

    // read the whole file in one hit
    is.read(*buff,*size);

    // Done. So close and zero delimit data.
    is.close();
    *(*buff+*size)=0;
}
```